# proof about linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Although I know the properties of linear transformations and the concept of rank, I could not prove this. Can you help me?

I chose an element from the kernel and said this element b. I saw that this element is a rangein element L (b) = sb for some numbers.

Comment: What is $s$ and what have you tried?

Comment: @ggg thank your answer. s scaler.I chose an element from the kernel and said this element b. I saw that this element is a in range element L (b) = sb for some numbers.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: @vajra Thanks your answers.You can find this question by author Bradley in his book primer of algebra.Chapter 4 exercise 9.The author made a suggestion as follows.Suggestion: Let  βbe any non-zero vector in RL.Then {β} is a basis for (RL),
(why?), and L( β) = sβ for some scalar y. Next, let a be α typical vector in V,
and show that (LoL)(α) = sL(α).

Comment: I hope my answer is clear. Let me know it :-)

Comment: new comment please check it. thank you so so much dear @Vajra.@vajra Thanks your answers.You can find this question by author Bradley in his book primer of algebra.Chapter 4 exercise 9.The author made a suggestion as follows.Suggestion: Let  βbe any non-zero vector in RL.Then {β} is a basis for (RL),
(why?), and L( β) = sβ for some scalar y. Next, let a be α typical vector in V,
and show that (LoL)(α) = sL(α).

Comment: Ok, I think it should be clear now. I wrote what you need to understand the solution to this problem

Comment: @Vajra (LoL)(a) = sL(a) this presentation confused me. How could such a situation exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that for a finite dimensional vector space $V$ we have $dim(V)=dim(ImF)+dim(kerF)$, where $F$ Is a linear map.
In your case $dim(ImF)=dimV-dim(KerF)=n-(n-1)=1\implies dim(KerF)=n-1$ and this means that the imagine of the map $F$ is generated by a vector $u$ such that $ImF=\langle u \rangle$.
For this reason, $\forall v\in V, F(v)\in \langle u \rangle\implies F(v)=\lambda u$, for $\lambda \in \mathbb K$.
This also shows that the composition $(F\circ F)(v)=F(F(v))=F(\lambda u)=\lambda F(u)$, which is still an element of $\langle u \rangle$.

Since the Kernel of the function is the eigenspace associated to te eigenvalue $t=0$, it could be interesting studying the diagonal form of the representative matrix of the map.